# conditional css only for safari and ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's say I have

```
<div class = 'x' />
```

It has some css properties and what is weird it is positioned differently in safari and last ie comparing to other browsers.
So I need to add css rule only if it is ie or safari:

```
.x { margin-left:10px;}
```

To make it look  the same as in chrome and ff=)
Js or jquery solution will be fine too=)

Comment: detect browser and apply changes to class according to need.

Comment: And did you include a CSS reset? Browser sniffing is generally not a very good idea.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score -1):

you can check use [jquery plugin](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) to detect browsers and based on results apply your css classes